# Dell xps 13 (3950) videocard not working

Tags: kernel, 15.10, dell, intel-graphics, i915

I'm a little new to this, so bear with me if the post does not follow the correct format 100%.

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed with kernel 4.5RC3 on a Dell XPS 13 9350 with i7 and followed this guide:

https://medium.com/@peterbrecska/dell-xps-13-linux-kernel-4-5-806cc94b1277#.ktyvgg1w4

Each time when i boot i get his error:

```
[ 3.070420] [drm:parse_csr_fw [i915]] *ERROR* Unknown stepping info,      firmware loading failed
[ 3.070439] [drm:csr_load_work_fn [i915]] *ERROR* Failed to load DMC   firmware , disabling rpm fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
```

I cannot watch videos without the whole system freezing and have to restart the computer.

Please ask if you need more information.

Comment: Why do you use an rc kernel? It is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a development kernel version.

Comment: The only reason for trying with a RC kernel was because i couldn't get it working with the 4.4.1 kernel and i found the guid which is mentioned in the question that uses the 4.5.

Comment: 4.4.1 is off-topic as well.

Answer (score -1):

disable DRI in Xorg until the driver is fixed in kernel, so that things will work without acceleration.

Comment: -1 for this is not a solution even if the title is offtopic